How to pass PowerShell string parameter that has both `(backtick), ' and " inside?
I am executing a Python script using a PowerShell command, The Python script takes a string that could contain special characters inside it. This parameter is passed from an ansible pipeline. The ansible host is a Windows Machine, therefore we have to use win_shell module which used PowerShell. So, the solution should be a general one that can be applied to any string. The PowerShell version I am running is PowerShell 5.1.
python.exe script.py --special_string the"str`in'g --otherparam value

But this gives errors. (Simply " and ' doesn't get skipped properly)
Based on my current findings,

In PowerShell ' means a literal string and " could be used to add variable values.
As the escape character we use `, but the`"strin`'g gives an error. "the`"strin`'g" doesn't work either. The error is, PowerShell considers the skipped ". Eith it takes all the remaining content in the command as the string content or closes already started string with " at the begining.

script.py: error: the following arguments are required: --otherparam


You cannot surround the string with " using ' like 'string"g'. This also gives an error.
Backtick can be escaped using double backticks or surrounding the string with single quotes. (making it a literal string)

What is the best way to do this?

"But this gives errors"  what errors do you get? If you are running a python script with python.exe, why use powershell at all (cmd would probably be better in this scenario)

if you do nt post the error we cannot kow f the problem is with Powershell or Python.

Backtick is the escape character in powershell since backslash is used in paths so much.

You can force PowerShell to skip parsing arguments of the python runtime. Just insert --% before the arguments of the external python.exe command:
python.exe --% script.py --special_string the"str`in'g --otherparam value

It will pass the arguments as is.

Thank you! This works. And learned the stop-parsing (--%) token prevents PowerShell from interpreting strings as PowerShell commands and expressions. This allows those strings to be passed to other programs for interpretation . This eliminated the requirement of adding escape characters of both PowerShell and the Python. Now I just need to add escape characters of Python which is much easier

Use double quotes to encapsulate the string and escape them and the backtick inside with the backtick
python.exe script.py --special_string "the`"str``in'g"


Yes this works from PowerShell perspective. But since this is passed into python, it gives an error with " inside the string. So I'm now testing with passing the \ as well. Like --special_string "the`"str``in'g"

perhaps "the\"str``in'g"` ? But that's a Python issue, not a Powershell one.

Yes, looks like "the`"str``in'g" works without an issue. But need to confirm the right string gets passed properly ignoring escape characters.
